# systemctl can't find executables while root can?

Tags: systemctl, exit-status

Strange thing: I've created a service, that should start a springboot fat archive webserver.
Service:

```
#!/bin/bash
[Unit]
Description=JalouWeb

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/jaloucontrol
ExecStart=/bin/bash jalouweb.sh

TimeoutStartSec=0
RestartSec=60
Restart=always
SyslogIdentifier=jalouweb

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

jalouweb.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh
#
java -Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar jcweb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Starting jalouweb.sh as user works.
Doing sudo -i and starting jalouweb.sh as root works.
Both user and root can call java -version sucessfully.

But when starting that service via systemctl, I receive

```
... jalouweb.sh: Zeile 3: java: Kommando nicht gefunden.(<- command not found)
...  systemd[1]: jalouweb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
```

As soon as I add path into jalouweb.sh:

```
/opt/openjdk17/bin/java -Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin...
```

systemctl also suceeds. But why?
Afaik running a service without user means running it as root. And root can start both sh as well as java directly. Why does systemctl need the explicit path?

---

EDIT: I followed advice of wenshuo:
No tmplog file is created despite service running sucessful, but journalctl shows

```
systemd[1]: Started JalouWeb. 
jalouweb[11189]:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin > /tmp/tmplog  
systemd[1]: jalouweb.service: Succeeded.
```

Seems so, as if the echo command is not really correct. But the core info is shown: No java in the path of the non-interactive root.

---

EDIT 2 @Stephane:
There is no problem with finding or executing the script. The problem is, that the called java within the script is not found. I have to figure out, how to give the executor of systemctl a path or a JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Can anybody explain, why this question was marked with -1? It caused two answers, one of them nearly two screen pages long by Stephane, who has a reputation of 505k.

Answer (score 1):

> <strike>`bash some-path`</strike>

Where *`some-path`* does not contain `/` characters should **not** be used. And that applies to several other Korn-like shells¹ as well as the `.` and `source` builtins² or many Bourne-like shells, though it's worse in `bash` specifically.

`bash` is the interpreter of the Bash programming language, just like `perl` is the interpreter for the `Perl` programming language.

`bash /path/to/some/Bash/file` like `perl /path/to/some/Perl/file` is how you tell `bash` or `perl` to interpret the Bash/Perl code in the given file as opposed to on stdin.

That's used for instance in:

```
#! /bin/bash -
```

Where upon execution, the system transforms it to `/bin/bash - path/to/the/file` and `bash` interprets the contents of the file.

With `/bin/bash some-path`, `systemd` is executing `bash`, but `bash` is not *executing* *`some-path`*³, it's just reading it and interpreting the Bash code in it.

Now, when *`some-path`* does not contain any `/`, the behaviour changes in `bash`. `bash` first interprets it as a normal path, so here a path relative to its current working directory, but if the file can't be found, it resorts to looking it up in the directory components of the `$PATH` environment variable (or if that is not set in some default search list).

That behaviour is *allowed* though not required by POSIX, though POSIX only allows *executable* files to be found in that process. Bash (at least version 5.2 here) would find even non-executable files, even when in POSIX mode which makes it non-compliant.

Here, either you need that script to be interpreted by `bash` from within the directory where it lies and then you need:

```
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/that/dir
ExecStart=/bin/bash ./the-script
```

(Note that `./` prefix which ensures the path contains a `/` and disables the `$PATH` look-up if for some reason `the-script` is missing from the current working directory).

If `WorkingDirectory` is not specified, it defaults to `/` for system services and the user's home directory for user ones.

Or you need to specify the full path of the script:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash /path/to/that/dir/the-script
```

If you indent `the-script` to be executable, and be interpreted by `bash` and be found by a `$PATH` look-up, then make sure it has a `#! /bin/bash -` shebang, that it has execute permissions (`chmod a+x`) and that it is stored in one of the directories in the `$PATH` used by `systemd`.

And use:

```
ExecStart=the-script
```

If that file is meant to be executable, I'd suggest removing that `.sh` extension. If not and if it's written in the Bash language, I'd suggest using a `.bash` extension rather than `.sh` which would be misleading if it's not standard `sh` syntax.

---

<sup>¹ that's the case of zsh when in sh or ksh emulation and ksh where that misfeature likely originates.</sup>

<sup>² for the `.` special builtin, that's worse as POSIX actually *requires* `/`-less paths be looked up in `$PATH` (and fall back to current working directory). A requirement which some shells ignore (including bash when not in POSIX mode).</sup>

<sup>³ that would be different in `bash -c the-script` where the `the-script` text here is given as inline shell code for bash to interpret, which bash interprets as a simple command resulting in it doing a `$PATH` look-up for an *executable* command (script or not) for it to *execute*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To find executables, the shell will search the directories listed in the `$PATH` variable. If `$PATH` includes the pathname of a directory, you can call executables in that directory without giving the full pathname of the executable.

With `echo "$PATH"` you can see your current list of paths in the shell.
In your case, `$PATH` used by `systemctl` is likely not the same as what's used for the `root` interactive shell.

You can see the value used in `$PATH` with `systemctl` by using

```
ExecStart=/bin/echo "$PATH" > /tmp/tmplog
```

... in the `[Service]` section of the unit file.  This would write the value of `$PATH` to `/tmp/tmplog`.

Comment: Note that here it's `bash some-script` not `bash -c some-script`, so it's not an *executable lookup*, it's just interpreting a script given as argument.